# How to make published workbook point published data source instead of its embedded data source

Tags: datasource, tableau-api

I have published workbook as well as its data source seperately. On server i found that workbook is pointing to its embedded data source and not published one. I want that published workbook to point its respective published data source and not embedded data source . How to do that. I have searched on Internet but I did not come across any sensible solution(As everyone was talking about how to connect to published data source  in workbook).
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Within Tableau desktop, connect to the published data source in your workbook. Then go to Data > Replace Data Source. Make sure everything still looks right after replacing the data source. Right click on the old data source to close it. Now you can republish and you'll be pointing to the server hosted data source.

Comment: k...Thanks friend..It helped